# What are the advantages of having a View per Controller

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am unsure as to what the advantages of having a `View` per `Controller` are? Anything I have read about `Views` has not clearly shown or demonstrated why you should have a `View` per `Controller`.

At the moment I have something like this (Shortened down to just the main methods):

```
interface ViewInterface {
    public function render();
}

class View implements ViewInterface {

    private $template;

    public function __construct($template = NULL) {

        if($template !== NULL) {
            $this->setTemplate($template);
        }
    }

    public function render() { 
        ob_start();
        require(PATH_TEMPLATES . $this->template . '.php');
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}

class CompositeView implements ViewInterface {

    private $views;

    public function attachView(ViewInterface $view) {
        $this->views[] = $view;
        return $this;
    }

    public function render() {

        $output = '';
        foreach($this->views as $view) {
            $output .= $view->render();
        }

        return $output;
    }

}
```

Let's say I want to render the privacy policy page, I can do it like this

```
$header = new View('common/header');
$body = new View('privacy-policy');
$footer = new View('common/footer');

$compositeView = new CompositeView();
$compositeView->attachView($header)
              ->attachView($body)
              ->attachView($footer);

$compositeView->render();
```

What is wrong with this? What advantages do you gain from having a separate `View` for each `Controller`?

Any advice would be great thanks.

Comment: I think you are effectively creating one view per controller there aren't you?

Comment: Is that what they mean by one `View` per `Controller`? I thought it ment one `View` as in the register page would have a `RegisterPage` View class and the login page would have a `Login` View class too. So is the way I was doing it all along correct?

Comment: No, you don't need a separate view class for each controller, but you do have a separate instance of a view class for each controller, if that makes sense? You are doing it more or less correct.

Comment: Everything I have seen they were saying you need a 1:1 relationship between Views and Controllers and I thought they were saying a separate View class for each View. I Started doing it that way and almost straight away I felt something was wrong so I came on here. Thanks for the reply I can just leave my implementation how it was all along which is great.

Comment: Your "views" have no UI logic in them. They are simply dumb templates.

Comment: There is more to my CompositeView and View classes which I left out above to minimize the amount of code. They have access to View Helpers which can do my logic. It is hard to learn this MVC thing. Too much writing and not enough solid examples. Getting there piece by piece.

Comment: Lets say you have `Controller\Login` and `View\Login`. In that case the view would be responsible for all th UI logic. You have at least two states when view would only respond HTTP header (for posted credentials and authenticated account). It also, based on state of the model layer, would present the authentication form(s), warnings, error messages, "page locked"/"user locked" information. And that's assuming that you have a login page with not RESTful interface or XHR-based behavior. This all would be done by the view and be part of the UI logic.

Comment: Thanks for that I will look into it. I am just starting to get my head around the Model layer and Controllers after learning them the wrong way from many different places at first. Thanks again.